# How to detect 3 consecutive empty rows in excel

Tags: excel, vba

I am new to VBA so sorry for the silly question.

I would like to detect if there are 3 consecutive empty rows in a column. I am aware that I could probably do 2 consecutive empty rows using code below:

```
While (lastCell <> "") Or (curCell <> "")
    lastCell = curCell
    ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Select
    curCell = ActiveCell
Wend
```

Is there a way to do 3 rows? Thank you so much.

Tried to run the code but nothing happened [image]

Comment: `3 consecutive empty rows` or `3 consecutive empty Cells say in Col A`?

Comment: Hi @SiddharthRout it's 3 consecutive empty rows in one `Col A`

Comment: Let me rephrase. Do you want to check if the complete row is empty (for example `A1:XFD1` in Excel 2007+) or just `A1`?

Comment: So in first example you compare `A1:XFD1` with `A2:XFD2` and so on. In the 2nd you compare `A1` with `A2` and so on...

Comment: I want to check for just single cell `A1` at a time, then for the whole column `A`

Comment: @SiddharthRout So basically I suspect that there are 3 consecutive empty rows in a column `Col A`, but I would like to check where are they

Comment: I posted an answer. You may have to refresh the page to see it.

Comment: @SiddharthRout Thank you so much for your answer. I tried to run the code but nothing happened. Please see the edited question for the screenshot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know if it would ever be the case, but this will detect if gaps are even bigger than 3 rows too.

```
Sub Test()

Dim lr As Long, x As Long
Dim rng1 As Range, rng2 As Range
Dim arr As Variant

With ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1") 'Change accordingly
    lr = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
    Set rng1 = .Range("A2:A" & lr)
    If Application.WorksheetFunction.CountA(rng1) <> rng1.Cells.Count Then
        Set rng2 = Intersect(rng1, rng1.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks))
        arr = Split(rng2.Address, ",")
        For x = LBound(arr) To UBound(arr)
            If .Range(arr(x)).Cells.Count > 2 Then
                Debug.Print arr(x)
            End If
        Next x
    End If
End With

End Sub
```

Comment: Hi @jvdV, thanks for your answer. I managed to run the code for a sample of data but somehow I couldn't do it for the entire data. I am thinking maybe the dataset is too big?

Comment: Well, @Harper, it depends what you meant with "Somehow I couldn't do it for the entire data". Does it throw an error? Or does it just not produce the result you are after? Notice the code looks at truely empty cells, not cells that are actually holding `""` through formula.

Comment: By that  mean there's nothing in the output after running the code. Yes I am sure the cells are actually empty.

Comment: @Harper, It's hard to believe the code runs without throwing an error nor output when cells are truely empty. Few more things I can think of, make sure to reference the correct sheet and workbook when you run the code, and again make sure there are no trailing/leading spaces or any other unseen characters in the cells. No matter how large my data, the code worked. You might want to include a screenshot of how your data looks too in your question. Maybe there are some leads there.

Comment: Okay maybe the problem lies with me but thank you guys I learnt a lot from both your contributions @Siddharth Rout

Comment: @Harper, how do you pull in your data? It could be tab delimited data, which is still a character in your cell you just won't see, but the cell just aint empty. Try replacing some of the cells that you feel should be empty with truely empty cells from even beyond your data set and re-run the code. Otherwise I'm out of ideas for now ;)